# Get execution duration of all functions running in the application

Tags: node.js

I am trying to optimize my node application and I am looking for a way to track all functions execution duration, including the async ones, in order to see what causes "slowness". After some reasearch I found this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/njstrace , however I am not sure it offers what I need.